# undefinedは、真偽判定に利用できる？

Tags: javascript

**下記のようなコードを見かけたのですが、どういう意味でしょうか？**
・第3引数を渡さないとき、cはundefinedになるため、常にfalse？
・第3引数を渡すとき、cは常にtrue？

```
function test (a, b, c) {
  //
  if (c) {
    //
 } else {
    //
 }
}
test(1, 2);
```

・これは一般的な書き方でしょうか？

Comment: JavaScriptでfalseと判定される、いわゆるFalsyな値についてはこちらのページをご参照ください。 [Falsy - 用語集 | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Glossary/falsy)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

すでに承認された回答が付いていますが、念のため補足です。

*・第3引数を渡さないとき、cはundefinedになるため、常にfalse？*
Yesです。true/false以外の値を論理値が必要な場所に渡した時に、どのようにtrue/falseに変換されるかは(harry0000さんのコメントにもありますが)しっかり定義されています。

[9.2 ToBoolean](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.2)
リンク先はECMA5.1のものですが、この部分の記述についてはバージョン間での本質的な変更はないはずです。

undefinedがfalseとして判定されることは(よほど変な独自実装をしていない限り)間違いありません。

*・第3引数を渡すとき、cは常にtrue？*
Noです。上のリンクを参照すればわかりますが、`undefined`, `false`, `null`, `+0`, `-0`, `NaN`, `''`(空文字列)は`false`と判定されます。ここにあげた値を第3引数として渡せばif(c)の判定は成立せず、「第3引数を渡しているのに条件は成立しない」と言うことになります。

あなたのコードでtest(1, 2, 0)を実行して、`if`部と`else`部のどちらが実行されるか確かめてみてください。

*・これは一般的な書き方でしょうか？*

「一般的」をどう定義すれば良いのかわからないので、直接の回答ではありませんが、「`undefined`, `false`, `null`, `+0`, `-0`, `NaN`, `''`」以外の値を全て真と判定したい場合にはよくある書き方、と言って良いと思います。

但し、「必須ではない引数を指定されたかどうか」を判定するには、この条件の書き方ではうまくいかないことも多いです。`0`や`''`を指定された場合に、それは何も指定していないものと扱って良いのかどうか、よく考えて、要件に合わないなら、`arguments.length`を使って判定すべきでしょう。

Comment: 第3引数を渡すときcは常にtrueではないことが良く分かりました(undefined, false, null, +0, -0, NaN … を引数として渡すことなど全く考慮していませんでした)。「必須ではない引数を指定されたかどうか」の判定はまた異なる要件となるわけですね。参考になりました

Answer (score 4):

一般的な書き方ですが、

```
function(a, b, c){
  if(!!c){
     someFunc(c); // cについて処理する
  } else{
     someFunc({}); // cがなかった時の処理
  }
  // ...
}
```

のように、 `if(!!c){ ...` というのも多いです。
たとえば、前述の `someFunc` は「引数にtrueかfalseが欲しい！ nullやundefinedはこまる！」
というようなときに、`someFunc(!!c)` とすれば、引数cを省略した時も、falseを入れた時も、trueが来た時も問題なく動きます。

`!!`のパターンもよく見るので一応覚えておいたほうが良いですよ

Comment: ＞!!のパターンもよく見るので…。二重否定演算子(検索して調べました)はこういう風に使うのですね。アドバイスありがとうございました

Answer (score 2):

省略可能なブール引数として使っています。
省略した場合、及び `false`、`0`、`""`など偽と判断される値を渡した場合はfalseとなります。
それ以外の値を渡した場合はtrueとなります。

一般的な書き方かと。